# iOS: Tap cancel in Messages app to go back to app that invoked it

Tags: ios, message, cancel-button

Our team manager has proposed the following idea: within our app, when a user taps a `Send Msg` button, our app opens up the Messages app. Our manager wants to tap `Cancel` to go back to our app (see screenshot below), instead of the top left `Go back to ...` shortcut in the status bar. Is that possible?

This is the picture:
[image: red frame show]

**UPDATE** The messageComposeViewController delegate method is like this, and I see some shaking when I dismiss the message controller?:****

```
#pragma mark - sms delegate

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller
                 didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:

            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:

            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:

            [LMLSendResultAlert showSuccessOrFail:0 withSuccesString:@"" andFailStr:@"短信发送失败" needPopOrdismiss:0 complete:nil];
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This is my viewWillAppear method:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: did you manage to use MFMessageComposeViewController and use the cancel button to go back to app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are opening the message editor externally, that is, you just open the default Message app (I guess this is what is happening, otherwise there wouldn't be the Back button at top left corner), unfortunately I'm not aware of any way to go back to your app when clicking the `Cancel` button.

However, if you are using `MFMessageComposeViewController`, which probably is a good idea as your users don't have to leave your app, it would be definitely possible to act accordingly when users choose to `cancel`.

You can take a look at Apple's doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668-CH1-SW4), which utilizes `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:`

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller
             didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
   // Check the result or perform other tasks.

   // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following what Stephenye has said, if you use MFMessageComposeViewController the cancel button will allow you to go back to your app (you will still be in your app anyway because you present the message controller as you present any other view controller).

Here is an example:

```
-(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    switch (result)
    {
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
                break;
            case MessageComposeResultFailed:
                [LMLSendResultAlert showSuccessOrFail:0 withSuccesString:@"" andFailStr:@"短信发送失败" needPopOrdismiss:0 complete:nil];
                break;
            case MessageComposeResultSent:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        }];

}

-(void)presentMessagerOnViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
{
    if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        //show error message
        return;
    }

    NSArray *recipients = @[@"0424456654"];
    NSString *defaulMessage = @"You should absolutely upvote my answer";

    MFMessageComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    composer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [composer setRecipients: recipients];
    [composer setBody: defaulMessage];
    [self presentViewController: composer animated:YES completion: NULL];
}
```

Comment: Yestoday I did not reach 15 reputation,now I upvote your answer.BTW: I want to ask you a question, I use the MFMessageComposeViewController, when I click the cancle button to dismiss the composer, it will shake several times then dismiss, did you run into this awkward situation?

Comment: @LeoMaer Yes, go ahead. No need to ask if you can ask :)

Comment: @LeoMaer it shakes? You mean there is a delay? Or is it the animation that is shaky while taking place.

Comment: I certain it is a bug in MFMessageComposeViewController, beacuse the ainmation is unsightly, and it was after shake up-down some times quickly then dismiss .

Comment: @LeoMaer apple wouldn't have such. Its something in your didFinishWithResult().  Post your didFinishWithResult() method and I will tell you what needs to be changed.

Comment: The comment frame has limit content, where to put my code?

Comment: @LeoMaer add the code your main question. Paste your code there. Highlight the code and then tap on `{}` to get it formatted.

Comment: I have token my code to main question, should I delete this code after got the solustion ?

Comment: @LeoMaer okay. You need to change one thing

Comment: @LeoMaer No do not delete the code. Let me edit the question for you. Make sure to approve the edit please.

Comment: @LeoMaer I just edited it. You should get a notification. Click the notification and approve the init (if you do really approve that is :)   not forcing here)

Comment: @LeoMaer see my answer now

Comment: @LeoMaer are you seeing shaking only when there is an error, or even when the message is successful? And what device are you using. Is it an old iPhone?

Comment: I did not send message and to click the cancle button, my iphone is 5c

Comment: @LeoMaer are you sure you have nothing inside `case MessageComposeResultCancelled:`

Comment: @LeoMaer can you show your viewWillAppear method please?

Comment: @LeoMaer I mean the viewWillAppear method for your viewController. Similar to viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear.  if you have it in your code please add in to your question

Comment: And I am sure the issue is not iphone's reason, I have tested the shake issue on iphone6.

Comment: @LeoMaer you are doing two different animations at the same time. When the message controller animates away, you are also animating the hiding of the navigation bar. try setting animated to NO, in your viewDidAppear. See if the shaking goes away. If it does then we know the culprit.

Comment: like this? -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    animated = NO;
}

Comment: @LeoMaer that is not how you hide a navigation bar.

Comment: @LeoMaer `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

Comment: @LeoMaer set animated to NO. If that does not make a difference then there is something else you are doing, coz i am not getting shaking here.

Comment: Thx your explain in patience, I have taken `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` ,but no use, I will have a look of other example to check if is my code run into wrong. If I found where is the issue, I will tell you.